# store url in userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling API wih 'Alamofire'. In my response I get one weblink. I store that weblink in to one variable. Now I want to store that weblink into the local database. so I use 'userdefaults'. But when I retrive that weblink into the other 'viewcontroller' at that time my weblink changed and web page didnot open.

```
let weblink = datastring["Web_Link"] as! String
UserDefaults.standard.set(weblink, forKey: "Link")
```

for these I use this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(url: URL?, forKey: String)
```

and in another 'viewcontroller'

```
let url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "Link")
```

for these I used

```
let url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: String)
```

and my other code is

```
 let request = URLRequest.init(url: url!)

 self.webview.load(request)
```

my url example is "https://example.com/"

but when I retrive at that time url is

```
'https:/example.com'
```

so my webpage cannot open. I am using wkwebview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store the url as string so retrieve it like this.

```
let url = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Link")
```

Comment: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL" this error into the  "let request = URLRequest.init(url: url!)" this code line

Comment: Convert url to URL type.
let request = URLRequest.init(url: URL(string: url!))

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are storing `String` value in user defaults and trying to get `URL` from UserDefaults. So Please try as like below.

```
let weblink = datastring["Web_Link"] as! String
    
if let url = URL(string: weblink){
        
    UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "Link")
}
```

Comment: `.synchronize()` is obsolete, it's been for a while now... It's explained in the documentation: please don't use it, and please please please stop telling people to use it.

Comment: I was not using UserDefaults recently since core-data arrived. Thanks for the pointing that out. Edited my answer. Cool.

Comment: Thank you for editing. The thing is, not only this is obsolete, but this can cause issues, because it forces the defaults to *wait* for all transactions to be finished before starting new ones. It is the *opposite* of "save now", actually. :)

Comment: Agreed. I think, iOS would save the changes in UserDefaults automatically when app moves to background or before terminates. Thanks again :)